# Format text block to fit 4 lines

Tags: css

I have been trying to get the block of text to fit on four lines with the first sentence on the first line.  Is there a way you can do this ?

http://test.darkrome.com/official-vatican-museum-partnership

Its the first text block after the blue heading.  I need 4 lines, font 23 or so Arial and the first sentence should be on the first line with no line breaks or paragraphs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get them on 4 lines by making the `width` of `#comTempFluid2` 850px.

```
#comTempFluid2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 850px;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

In order to keep the first sentence on the same line, remove the first sentence and put it in its own `<p>` tag or `<span>` tag. It will have the same width applied as it would be a child element.

Comment: but i need the first sentence on the first line only .. sentence cant go past into the second line

Comment: @Aindriu I would add the first sentence in a different `<p>` tag or `<span>` tag then. And set the width to the same.

Comment: i think i am going to have to do that.. its a lot of work jsut to get the formatting right

Comment: @Aindriu CSS related things can be annoying sometimes. I've updated my answer, hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the same `font` and `font-size`, make the box wider and decrease left margin.

```
#comTempFluid2 {
    margin-left: 80px; /* you have 100px */
    width: 840px;      /* you have 800px */
}
```

PS. remember that there are users without `arial`, they will see another font which can be smaller/larger. Then text will be on 3.5 or 5 lines.

Comment: is there any way I can make the text go out extra on line 3 and line 4 - it keeps getting narrower and then makes a fifth line

Comment: HTML is live, it's not paper. Text flow is different in different browsers. Forget there is any _ideal_ solution.

Comment: Only what you can do is put `<br>` after the first sentence.

Comment: You have text which is with defined font, font-size and width on 5 lines. You want to have 1st line shorter without hard line breaking. It's not possible using CSS. You can have either 4 lines, 1st line will be more than first sentence, or 5 lines when 1st line will be just 1st sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a span-element by defining the following in your CSS:

```
span{
    display:block;
}
```

Then use the span element in your HTML file for your first sentence.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/marc_g/5frhzd6f/